# How can I make use of this git repository folder?

Tags: git, gogs

I am rescuing a disk that has a Gogs installation. There's a folder with all the git repos stores, they individually look like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sardaukar 4.0K Jul 29 21:51 branches/
-rw-r--r--. 1 sardaukar   66 Jul 29 21:51 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 sardaukar   73 Jul 29 21:51 description
-rw-r--r--. 1 sardaukar   23 Jul 29 21:51 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sardaukar 4.0K Jul 29 21:51 hooks/
drwxr-xr-x. 2 sardaukar 4.0K Jul 29 21:51 info/
drwxr-xr-x. 4 sardaukar 4.0K Jul 29 21:51 objects/
-rw-r--r--. 1 sardaukar   98 Jul 29 21:51 packed-refs
drwxr-xr-x. 4 sardaukar 4.0K Jul 29 21:51 refs/
```

Is there a way I can salvage this and clone these repos again? I have around 20 of them. Not looking to go back to Gogs, just want to be able to clone these repos again...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have rescued is a so-called bare repository which is the content of the hidden `.git` folder in your clone. Just save this directory on a computer with openssh running, say you save it to `~/repo` with `~` being the home of the user `user`, you can clone with:

```
git clone user@<your-computer>:~/repo
```

`your-computer` is the computer with the ssh server running, if you clone on the same computer write `localhost` here.

**EDIT (Thanks to [Don Branson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667372/how-can-i-make-use-of-this-git-repository-folder/38667457?noredirect=1#comment64716049_38667457)):** If you are cloning your local machine, you can also write:

```
git clone /path/to/repo
```

Comment: Actually, if you clone it on the same computer, same user, just `git clone ~/repo`.